# I could not catch your call

Tags: expressions

Is the following expression acceptable especially in formal register when you miss a call and text back to someone as " I am sorry. I missed your call". What are other the fix expressions can be used in text messaging.

> I am sorry. I couldn't catch your call

Comment: It's not idiomatic in US English.  You already know the most common one: **I missed your call.**

Comment: @stangdon I was wondering if it could be acceptable in BrE. I remember hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

Very standard is

> I'm sorry. I missed your call.

this is the most standard way of saying this and can be used formally and informally.

If you need to use "couldn't", your sentence should be reformulated to

> I'm sorry. I **couldn't** answer your call.

otherwise, you could say

> I'm sorry, I **didn't** catch your call.

in your expression "answer" is usually used instead of "catch", and "didn't" is usually used instead of "couldn't" the reason for the latter is because you may have to explain your inability to answer the phone, "couldn't" = "not able to".

Answer (score 0):

The "catch" part is perhaps slightly informal. A possible replacement may be: "I am sorry I was not available to take your call" (or "I was unable to take your call") or as the comments and your question states "I missed your call"